# How to add a little space between comparators and a number using siunitx?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, siunitx, comparison

I'm using `siunitx` package for the numbers and units. When I use a comparator, like `\sim`, the symbol is placed without any space. I'd like to set `siunitx` to add a little space like in inline math mode, e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
$\sim 4500$ $\longleftarrow$ like this\par
\num{\sim 4500}\par
\SI{\sim 4500}{}\par
\SI{4500}[\sim]{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `\newcommand{\ssim}{\sim\,}` and then use `\ssim` instead.

Comment: @Werner it doesn't work here: `\SI{\ssim 4500}{}`  but works here: `\SI{4500}[\sism]{}` and can be done like `\SI{4500}[\sim\;]{}` to be more close to the space he asks for.

Comment: @Werner One has to add `\ssim` to the list of comparators.

Comment: Are you sure you want it?

Comment: @egreg No, I'm not. Why I souldn't add the space?